# How can I only load a process in RAM but not run (start)? (c#)

Tags: c#, optimization, process, ram

I want to execute several exe files sequentially. I need to execute the first process and also only load another process (the second) into RAM. When the first process is finished, the second process is started. Since the second process has already been loaded we don't have a delay to switch between them.

Comment: If you have access to the source code of the executable which you're trying to run, you can modify it to wait upon a Mutex or another synchronization mechanism before it performs its logic. Then you can signal that Mutex from your calling application at the right time.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing that comes into mind is to use lower level calls to Win32 API. You can create a process suspended and then resume the main thread calling ResumeThread.

Maybe the following code can help you ? **Edit: Added some comments which might help understand better the code:**

```
    // Structures needed by CreateProcess API
    public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
    {
        public IntPtr hProcess;
        public IntPtr hThread;
        public uint dwProcessId;
        public uint dwThreadId;
    }
    public struct STARTUPINFO
    {
        public uint cb;
        public string lpReserved;
        public string lpDesktop;
        public string lpTitle;
        public uint dwX;
        public uint dwY;
        public uint dwXSize;
        public uint dwYSize;
        public uint dwXCountChars;
        public uint dwYCountChars;
        public uint dwFillAttribute;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public short wShowWindow;
        public short cbReserved2;
        public IntPtr lpReserved2;
        public IntPtr hStdInput;
        public IntPtr hStdOutput;
        public IntPtr hStdError;
    }

    public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
    {
        public int length;
        public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
        public bool bInheritHandle;
    }


    public class MyProcess : IDisposable
    {
        PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();
        // Look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684863(v=vs.85).aspx for more information about process creation flags
        private const int CREATE_SUSPENDED = 0x00000004;
        public bool CreateProcess(string filename)
        {
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            // Create a Win32 process started suspended. pi will hold the handles to the process and main thread
            return CreateProcess(filename, null, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, false, CREATE_SUSPENDED, IntPtr.Zero, null, ref si, out pi);
        }
        public void Start()
        {
            // Start the process which is currently suspended by resuming the main thread
            ResumeThread(pi.hThread);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // Handles to the thread and process must be released when done so no memory leaks occur
            CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
            CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        }


        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static private extern bool CreateProcess(string lpApplicationName, string lpCommandLine, IntPtr lpProcessAttributes, IntPtr lpThreadAttributes,
                                bool bInheritHandles, uint dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
                                string lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        static private extern uint ResumeThread(IntPtr hThread);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hObject);
    }
```

Comment: Not everything can be done directly with the .net framework.  Fortunately,  .net lets you pinvoke low level native Win32 API functions.  Thus anything you can do in a native C Win32 program,  theoretically you can do in your c# code.

Comment: Sorry.  I pressed post by mistake. In this case we are using CreateProcess to create a process but give it a flag to tell windows to create the process in suspended mode.  Then you can call ResumeThread to unfreeze the main thread of the process and let it startup